# using form textfield name from dynamic table outside whileloop

Tags: php

I got another problem with my Code.

I  generate a dynamic table from SQL-content and use textfields in the table to, maybe someday, change the content.

The problems is, I cann't access the textfields from outside the whileloop to save the content, all I get is Undefined index error for every field.

```js
<form method="POST" enctype="text/html">


<?php

require_once ('config.php');
$sql = " SELECT * FROM kassen ORDER BY name ASC ";
$db_erg = mysql_query( $sql );



echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo '<table border="1" width="80%" align="center">';

echo "<tr> <th>Name</th><th>Stand</th><th>Verbrauch</th><th>Einzahlungen</th></tr>";

while ($zeile = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_erg))
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'. $zeile['name'] . '</td>'; 
echo '<td><center>'. $zeile['bier_stand'] . '€</td>'; 
echo '<td>';

/* in the text below, i set the name to verbrauch"'.$zeile['id'] and
ergebnis"'.$zeile['id'] which should generate a new unique name for every
single text*/

echo '<center><input type="text" name="verbrauch"'.$zeile['id'].' value="0" size="10" />';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<center><input type="text" name="einzahlung"'.$zeile['id'].' value="0" size="10" />';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}   echo '</table>';


?>
<center><input type="hidden" name="aktion" value="speichern" />
<center><input type="Submit" name="" value="speichern"/>
</form>

<?php

if (isset ($_POST['aktion']))
{
if ($_POST['aktion'] == "speichern" )
{
require_once ('config.php');
$sql = " SELECT * FROM kassen ORDER BY name ASC ";
$db_erg = mysql_query( $sql );

while ($zeile = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_erg))
    {
    $standalt   = $zeile["bier_stand"];

    /* now I try to put the value of the text to the DB, but all i get is 
    Undefined Index error */

    $verbrauch  = $_POST['verbrauch'.$zeile['id']];
    $einzahlung = $_POST['einzahlung'.$zeile['id']];


    $stand      = $zeile["bier_stand"] - $verbrauch + $einzahlung;
    $id         = $zeile["id"];

    $sql = "UPDATE kassen SET ";
    $sql .= " bier_stand_alt    = '$standalt', ";
    $sql .= " bier_stand        = '$stand', ";
    $sql .= " bier_verbrauch    = '$verbrauch', ";
    $sql .= " bier_einzahlungen = '$einzahlung' ";  
    $sql .= " WHERE id='$id'";
    }
echo '<h2>Änderungen übernommen</h2>';
echo '<a href="bierkasse.php">zurück zur Bierkasse</a>';
exit;
}
}

?>
```

Any idea what I'm messing up?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are asking, but I would recommend moving your form processing code to the top of the file.

Comment: `if( isset($_POST['aktion']) && $_POST['aktion'] == 'speichern' )`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for questioning,

realy stupid mistake

```
echo '<center><input type="text" name="einzahlung"'.$zeile['id'].' value="0" size="10" />';
```

should have been

```
 echo '<center><input type="text" name="einzahlung'.$zeile['id'].'" value="0" size="10" />';
```

so actually just the " was in wrong place ... stupid stuff that happens at 3am